# How to send data from template to an included component in Angular?

Tags: angular

This is a example component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  setTestVar: string = '';
  testVar: string = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testVar = this.setTestVar;
  }
}
```

You can use it like this from another components template:

```
...
<app-test [setTestVar]="variable_from_calling_component"></app-test>
...
```

But how can I set a value that don't exists as variable inside the calling component. How can I use a value that is just defined inside the calling template?

```
...
<app-test [setTestVar]="some_value"></app-test> /** does not work **/
...
```

Comment: If you mean a literal string, you could do something like : <app-test [setTestVar]="'some_value'"></app-test> OR like : <app-test setTestVar="some_value"></app-test>, setTestVar will therefore contain the value :"some_value"

Comment: thank you, both solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input of your component expects a string. If you are using the [] brackets in angular it expects a method name or variable that exists in the typescript file. If you want to pass a new string then use:

```
<app-test [setTestVar]="'some_value'"></app-test>
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
<app-test setTestVar="some_value"></app-test>
```

Comment: I didn't know, that I can fetch attributes with the input decorator.